# Trigger a logout from a liferay portlet

Tags: java, liferay

Being quite new to liferay/portal/portlet development you run into problems daily . Now i'm trying to for a logout from a portlet but have not found a way to accomplish that. How are you supposed to do that? Should I try to send some kind of logout event or something? Greping around in the liferay sources i have found a LogoutAction.java that seems promising but how do one trigger that?

Best Regards Anders Olme

Comment: Why don't you render the regular logout link?

Comment: I have to trigger the logout from one of my beans.

Comment: But can you get to such url from the portlet bean?

Answer (score 3):

try actionResponse.sendRedirect("/c/portal/logout")

Comment: sendRedirect is only on ActionResponse, not RenderResponse or ResourceResponse.

Answer (score 1):

PortletSession.invalidate() ?

Comment: That just invalidates the portlet but the other portlets are still up and running and the portal user is still logged in.

Comment: Guess a more correct title would have been to trigger a portal logout.

Comment: I've found that there is LogoutAction mapped to /portal/logout, so redirecting there or providing link could work. I've not tried it yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a log out link to Liferay's internal logout functionality like this one in your JSP:

```
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil"%>
.
.
<a href="<%= PortalUtil.getPortalURL(request) %>/c/portal/logout">Log Out</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

After 2-3 days of investigating I achieved logging in and out with ajax calls. To logout it is not as simple as calling the session.invalidate() but there is only a little more to configure. I will write how I achieved this:

First edit your portal-ext.properties and add this line:
session.enable.phishing.protection=false

Then in ALL of your portlets you have to set the private-session-attributes to false. The ordering is important so I'll show you mines:

```
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>home</portlet-name>
    <icon>/icon.png</icon>
    <instanceable>false</instanceable>
    <private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>
    <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
    <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/home.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
    <css-class-wrapper>home-portlet</css-class-wrapper>
</portlet>
```

Once did this the rest is pretty simple. For log in:

```
public static void login(ResourceRequest request,ResourceResponse response, String liferayUser, String liferayPassword) throws Exception{
    MethodKey key = new MethodKey("com.liferay.portlet.login.util.LoginUtil", "login", HttpServletRequest.class, HttpServletResponse.class, String.class, String.class, boolean.class, String.class);
    PortalClassInvoker.invoke(false, key, new Object[] { PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(request), PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(response), liferayUser, liferayPassword, false, null});       
}
```

And for log out:

```
public static void logout(ResourceRequest resourceRequest) throws Exception{
    HttpServletRequest request = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(resourceRequest); 
    request.getSession().invalidate();
}
```

I used ResourceRequest because i was doing Ajax calls. The only "problem" is that if you are logged in and want to logout & login with another user you have to do 2 ajax calls (the second one once returned from the first one).